# win32api vs Python

Tags: python, winapi, io

What are the Pro's and Con's of using win32api for I/O and other things instead of simply Python, if both have a specific function for it

I mean, using PyWin32 vs Win32Api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**con**

- (lack of) portability
- harder/more error prone

**pro**

- performance (potentially, it must be measured, as will depend on more than just the api calls)

Comment: Do you have benchmarks that back up your performance claim? (Especially since python now has an I/O implementation in C)

Comment: @Arafangion Not specifically for I\O, but he said "I/O and other things".  Perf is always something you have to verify in your particular case.  I will add detail there.

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious thing seems to be losing cross-platform compatibilty. Python runs on a number of different platforms, none of which has a win32 API except MS Windows.